# How does this BJT circuit produce 0V at output for any input dc voltage?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I've been trying to understand how the dc bias is removed at the ouput inside an op amp. Below circuit seems to work
[image]

Some explanation is given below by the author

> To shift the output dc level to zero, level translator circuits are
>   used. An emitter follower with voltage divider is the simplest form of
>   level translator as shown in fig. 2.
>
> Thus a dc voltage at the base of Q produces 0V dc at the output. It is
>   decided by R1 and R2.

But I don't quite get how **R1** and **R2** manage to maintain **0V** at the **output** no matter what dc value we put at the **Input**. As the *Input* changes, \$V_{CE}\$ of the transistor \$Q\$ varies on the load line, so I don't see how the **o/p** can stay at **0V**. Appreciate any help.

Comment: My work so far :  
KVL through output loop gives
 
$$V_{CC}-V_{CE} - I_C(R_1+R_2) +V_{EE}= 0 $$

Comment: do not put additional information into comments .... please add the info to your question and delete the comment

Comment: Ohk.. sorry I thought my question was getting too big, I'll try adding it to the question :)

Comment: You must have left some context out of what you quoted from your book. There is one particular input voltage that produces 0 V output. Other input voltages will produce different output voltages.

Comment: @ThePhoton I copied the circuit and explanation from http://www.nptel.ac.in/courses/117107094/lecturers/lecture_5/lecture5_page1.htm

Comment: @ThePhoton Btw thank you, so if this circuit really doesn't maintain  0V for all Inputs, I think the author's claim is wrong and I can happily stop worrying haha ;)

Comment: Normally dc is biased near mid range if Vcc- Vee for maximum AC swing which can be 0V but better designs use comple

Answer (score 3):

DC bias for Vb is chosen such that ...

(Vb-Vbe/|Vee|=R1/R2.

Although this design is less efficient than others since R1+R2 raises output impedance yet must be much smaller than load R.

Comment: +1 for making me remember what pipe symbols mean (vertical bars) ... lol

Comment: Ahh so as @The Photon says the output is 0V only for one particular dc  Input. I think I know how the condition given by you  produces the virtual ground at the output. Let me grab pen and paper and work a bit. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

There is one particular input voltage that produces 0 V output. Other input voltages will produce different output voltages.

From comments, you said you got this circuit from [course notes](http://www.nptel.ac.in/courses/117107094/lecturers/lecture_5/lecture5_page1.htm) about op-amp design. This is the 3rd stage of an example op-amp design.

In this context, you would design the circuit (choose R1 and R2) so that the output voltage is 0 when the input voltage is at the bias point reached when the op-amp's input voltage is (exactly) 0 V. Then any change in the whole circuit's input voltage will shift the output above or below 0.

If you want to analyze the circuit using KVL, the more useful loop to consider is the one that incudes the source driving this circuit, Q's b-e junction, R1, R2, and the -VEE source.

Comment: You're my savior! I get it! $$V_b-V_{BE}-I_CR_1 = 0;  I_CR1+V_{EE}=0$$ 

Above two equations give the ratio of resistors we must choose to maintain 0V for a particular \$V_b\$. This \$V_b\$ is actually known to us because it comes from the previous stage. Awesome! Thanks again :)